# Understanding pdo mysql transactions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

The [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php) says:

> If you've never encountered transactions before, they offer 4 major
> features: Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation and Durability (ACID). In
> layman's terms, any work carried out in a transaction, even if it is
> carried out in stages, is guaranteed to be applied to the database
> safely, and without interference from other connections, when it is
> committed.

**QUESTION:**

Does this mean that I can have two separate php scripts running transactions simultaneously without them interfering with one another?

---

**ELABORATING ON WHAT I MEAN BY** "*INTERFERING*"**:**

Imagine we have the following `employees` table:

```
 __________________________
|  id  |  name  |  salary  |
|------+--------+----------|
|  1   |  ana   |   10000  |
|------+--------+----------|
```

If I have two scripts with similar/same code and they run at the exact same time:

**script1.php** and **script2.php** (both have the same code):

```
$conn->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->execute(['ana']);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$salary = $row['salary'];
$salary = $salary + 1000;//increasing salary

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE employees SET salary = {$salary} WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->execute(['ana']);

$conn->commit();
```

and assuming the sequence of events is as follows:

- **script1.php** selects data
- **script2.php** selects data
- **script1.php** updates data
- **script2.php** updates data
- **script1.php** commit() happens
- **script2.php** commit() happens

What would the resulting salary of ana be in this case?

- Would it be 11000? And would this then mean that 1 transaction will overlap the other because the information was obtained before either commit happened?
- Would it be 12000? And would this then mean that regardless of the order in which data was updated and selected, the `commit()` function forced these to happen individually?

Please feel free to elaborate as much as you want on how transactions and separate scripts can interfere (or don't interfere) with one another.

Comment: I'm pretty sure an `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation` error will pop up for one of those scripts. The question is which one if they both run at the exact same time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not going to find the answer in php documentation because this has nothing to do with php or pdo.

Innodb table engine in mysql offers 4 so-called [isolation levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) in line with the sql standard. The isolation levels in conjunction with blocking / non-blocking reads will determine the result of the above example. You need to understand the implications of the various isolation levels and choose the appropriate one for your needs.

To sum up: if you use serialisable isolation level with autocommit turned off, then the result will be 12000. In all other isolation levels and serialisable with autocommit enabled the result will be 11000. If you start using locking reads, then the result could be 12000 under all isolation levels.

Answer (score 9):

Judging by the given conditions (a solitary DML statement), you don't need a transaction here, but a table lock. It's a very common confusion.

You need a transaction if you need to make sure that **ALL your DML statements were  performed correctly or weren't performed at all.**

Means

- you don't need a transaction for any number of SELECT queries
- you don't need a transaction if only one DML statement is performed

Although, as it was noted in the excellent answer from Shadow, you *may* use a transaction here with appropriate isolation level, it would be rather confusing. What you need here is *[table locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html)*. InnoDB engine lets you [lock particular rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html) instead of locking the entire table and thus should be preferred.

In case you want the salary to be 1200 - then use table locks.

Or - a simpler way - just run an *atomic* update query:

```
UPDATE employees SET salary = salary + 1000 WHERE name = ?
```

In this case all salaries will be recorded.

If your goal is different, better express it explicitly.

But again: you have to understand that transactions in general **has nothing to do with separate scripts execution.** Regarding your topic of *race condition* you are interested not in transactions but in table/row locking. This is a very common confusion, and you better learn it straight:

- a transaction is to ensure that **a set** of **DML** queries within **one script** were executed successfully.
- table/row locking is to ensure that other script executions won't interfere.

The only topic where transactions and locking interfere is a [deadlock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177433%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but again - it's only in case when a transaction is using locking.

Comment: I think the question was aimed at understanding the letter I from ACID, rather than performing a specific action in a specific way. At least this is how I interpreted it. I do not agree with what you wrote about table locking. In innodb you can do row level locking with a select statement, so you do not have to lock the entire table to get 12000 in the end. I agree that in the above code there is no need for the select, since the whole operation can be executed in a single update. But if this is only an example aimed at understanding isolation of transactions, then it serves the purpose.

Comment: I am using "table locking" as a general term, while noting that with innodb a row-level locking should be preferred. So I assume your comment as a rather terminology issue. While regarding the question meaning, I am probably the best guy around in terms of understanding questions, answering for 15 years already. ACID question as an XY problem for the OP, for which they just came across researching their particular problem. Either way, I think that both our answers corroborate each other, make it better for the reader.

Answer (score 5):

Alas, the "without interference" needs some help from the programmer.  It needs `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` to define the extent of the 'transaction'.  And...

Your example is inadequate.  The first statement needs `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  This tells the transaction processing that there is likely to be an `UPDATE` coming for the row(s) that the `SELECT` fetches.  That warning is critical to "preventing interference".  Now the timeline reads:

- script1.php BEGINs
- script2.php BEGINs
- script1.php selects data (`FOR UPDATE`)
- script2.php selects data is blocked, so it waits
- script1.php updates data
- script1.php commit() happens
- script2.php selects data (and will get the newly-committed value)
- script2.php updates data
- script2.php commit() happens

(Note: This is not a 'deadlock', just a 'wait'.)