# MySQL queue transactions

Tags: mysql, multithreading, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a queue in my database (one table has a column, that is an enum and has Queue, Completed and Working states) and I execute transactions on it, which changes the certain rows state from working to queue or working to complete, but first I have to run a complex query to select a row.
So right now, **first** the application runs a select, gets a row, **then** runs an update, to change the state from Queue to Working (inside a transaction, **the application is an API, written in Spring Boot** and I use the **jdbctemplate** to access the MySQL database, the method I use for this select and change state is marked with **`@Transactional`** annotation).
Also, the application (**that is using the API!**) is multi threaded, so it is possible, that two or more of this transaction will run at the same time (multiple calls for the API).

Is it possible, them to return the same row? 
Example: T1, T2 are transactions, S1,S2 selects, U1,U2 updates.
Execution order: T1 starts the same time as T2

```
T1 { S1 --->U1 }

  T2 { S2 ----->U2}
```

The 2nd select runs before the first update, so can they both return the same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that the 2 select statements return the same record with the same values, it all depends on the locking and isolation level you apply while querying the data.

See [Understanding pdo mysql transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557110/understanding-pdo-mysql-transactions) SO topic for further details.

Comment: If I understand correctly, changing the isolation level, does not help me, they still can select the same rows.

Comment: If you use serialisable isolation level, then the 2 transactions cannot select the same row. This isolation level in effect causes MySQL to lock every record a select touches. But you can achieve the same with explicit row level locking.

Comment: My select on selects a single row (uses LIMIT 1 at the end), so the isolation level should do it then.

Comment: Pls read the linked topic carefully, not just my answer, but @YourCommonSense's excellent addition as well. You seem to have a select followed by a single update, where no transaction may be needed at all, or even if you need transactions, you can achieve what you want through locking.