# Concurrent UPDATE's on MySQL TRIGGER

Tags: mysql

I have this TRIGGER in MySQL:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`view_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `views` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE metrics SET met_nu_vie = met_nu_vie + 1 WHERE usp_id = NEW.usp_id;   
END
```

Basically, when an user receives a 'view' from another user in a web application, the system creates a new row in table 'views', and after insert, increments a counter value in another table (metrics).

My question is: If the user receives 10 concurrent views from 10 different users... ¿is this UPDATE safe?

All tables on my schema are INNODB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user receives X concurrent views, then the counter eill be incremented by X with the update statement in the question.

As mysql manual on [innodb locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html) explains:

> UPDATE ... WHERE ... sets an **exclusive** next-key lock on every record
>   the search encounters. However, only an index record lock is required
>   for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a
>   unique row.

Mysql manual on exclusive locks says:

> If a transaction T1 holds an exclusive (X) lock on row `r`, a request
>   from some distinct transaction T2 for a lock of either type [exclusive or shared] on `r`
>   cannot be granted immediately. Instead, transaction T2 has to wait for
>   transaction T1 to release its lock on row `r`.

To sum it up: the viewers may be concurrent at your application level, but at mysql level updates are serialised using exclusive locks.

Comment: Thanks Shadow. But I have a doubt: In this page, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html, there is an example to increment a counter in a table:

SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;

Is my solution different than this one? Don't I need to use SELECT... FOR UPDATE?

Comment: Nope, you do not have to. You are using an atomic update. That's just an example. See the answers (not just mine!) in another, similar, but more generic question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557110/understanding-pdo-mysql-transactions