# Does `UPDATE SET WHERE` have concurrency issues?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, innodb

Consider the statement below

```
UPDATE SET is_locked = 1 WHERE id = 1 and is_locked = 0;
```

Does it have consistency problem under concurrent updates? Why?

(MySQL 5.7, with transaction isolation level of REPEATABLE-READ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not, since update requires an exclusive lock on the record being updated and innodb will not grant more than 1 exclusive lock on a record at a time.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I have read that update requires exclusive lock for several places including the reference manual, but most are for the use of FOR UPDATE. I am not sure whether there is any difference between UPDATE and FOR UPDATE under this context.

Comment: For update clause is used with selects. Next time pls include these points in your question, not in a separate subsequent comment.

Comment: Uh, there are differences depending on the usage, but that's a completely different question.

Comment: are they both use the same exclusive lock?

Comment: Yes, they do use the same exclusive lock - differences come in the usage.

Comment: See this SO question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557110/understanding-pdo-mysql-transactions

Answer (score 1):

(To address some comments)

In many (not all) situations, this is the pattern to follow:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
use the data from the SELECT to make decisions, then
UPDATE the row(s) selected
COMMIT.
```

If you leave off the `FOR UPDATE`, then some other connection could sneak in and change the row(s), only to have your `UPDATE` clobber those changes.  (Of course, there are cases where this is "OK".)

As for

```
UPDATE tbl SET is_locked = 1 WHERE id = 1 and is_locked = 0;
```

there is no issue.  That statement, regardless of how you run it, is "atomic".  No other connection can sneak in and mess with you.  (However, it is logically idempotent, so it is not an issue.)

By "regardless", I refer to `autocommit`, `BEGIN`, `tx_isolation_mode`, etc.